# Youtube V3 API - How to set APIKey

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

Youtube API newbie here.  I cant seem to figure out how to set an APIKey while running queries that do not require a oAuth. 
I haven't been able to find any examples as well.

I am trying to invoke [VideoCategories.List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) using Java API like this -

`

```
  String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");  // Where does this go.? 
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {

            }
        }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();


        List<VideoCategory> categories = youtube.videoCategories().list("snippet").setRegionCode("US").execute().getItems();
```

`

However, I cant figure out a place holder to set my apiKey.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out through another post.

The apiKey is set like this -

`

```
 youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {

        }
    }).**setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(apiKey)**.setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();
```

`